# NodeJS ,getting csv file output after loop

Tags: html, node.js, csv

I am trying to retrieve the information from the csv file and display it on the html but i am getting an error (**Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end**).
From my understanding, its because the response end before the loop is completed. How should i end a response after a loop?

```
var data = fs.readFileSync("data.csv", "utf8");
data = data.split("\n"); // SPLIT ROWS
for (let i in data) { // SPLIT COLUMNS
var count = 0;

  data[i] = data[i].split(",");
         let name =data[i][count];
         let age=data[i][count+1];

         response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
           response.write("<p>Name: " +name+ "</p>");
           response.write("<p>Age: " +age+ "</p>");
           response.end();
}
console.log(data);

}
```

Comment: If you try to move the response process (reponse.writeHead, response.end) out of the loop, it should be fine.

Comment: aye, thanks! got it solved! just need to move the response.end outside the loop too